# Overwrite default (Bartik) block.html.twig from my custom block module folder

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I have a custom block module. I want to override `core/themes/bartik/templates/block.html.twig` in `my-module` directory.

In `my-module` directory I have a folder `templates/` and the twig file `block--my-module.html.twig`.

In `modules/custom/my-module/my-module.module` i have:

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return array(
     'my_module' => array(
     'variables' => array('message' => NULL),
     'template' => 'block--my-module'
    ),
  );
}
```

If I insert in my `build()` function in `modules/custom/my-module/src/Plugin/Block/MyModule.php` e.g:

```
'#theme' => 'my_module',
```

my twig template is loaded from `modules/custom/my-module/templates/block--my-module.html.twig`, but as a child inside the default block.html.twig `core/themes/bartik/templates/block.html.twig`?

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @leymannx thanks so what I understand is I have to make a theme_suggestions for my block `function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)`, but how exactly?

Comment: Yes, exactly! `:-)`

Comment: @leymannx but what I don't understand is, there are already theme hook file name suggestions for my block? But at the moment my twig file is not overriding the `core/themes/bartik/templates/block.html.twig` twig file?

Comment: Try to add ‘base hook’ => ‘block’ and clear the cache

Comment: I have already ‘base hook’ => ‘block’. Now I made a theme_suggestion for my block and now it's overriding the default block template. But it's not parsing my $variables anymore...? Do I have to add something extra in my build() function now?

Comment: Try to take a look here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200085/whats-wrong-with-my-code-to-overwrite-a-block-template

Comment: @Jdrupal this works if you want to make an extra template file INSIDE the default block structure and markup. In my case I have to override the default block template file.

Comment: @leymannx if I do `{{ kint(content) }}` in `modules/custom/my-module/templates/block--my-module.html.twig` I see a `content array(3)`. How do I print those values now in my twig, like e.g `{{ test_var }}`

Comment: That's a new question.

Comment: I got it `{{ content['#test_var'] }}`

Comment: @leymannx what do I have to do with my question now? Can you remove it? Because of it's (kind of) duplicate..

Comment: Nothing, just leave it as it is. It's fine. This will help future readers which are incoming by exactly these search terms.